# Changing Color of a row based upon the table cell value

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to change the color of the table row if the cell contained certain text inside that row. For example, if the cell has value  Failed, row will turn red. But only one row is acting the way it should.

Here is my code.

CSS:

```
<style>    
   .failed {
       background: red !important;
       color: white !important;
   }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Session Eamil</th>
            <th>Login Url</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{ var counter = 1;}
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">@counter</td>
                    <td>@item.SessionEmail</td>
                    <td>@item.LoginUrl</td>
                    <td>@item.CreatedAt.ToLocalTime().ToString("G")</td>
                    <td>@item.Status</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a href='@Url.Action("JobDetail","ArchivedScrapeJob", new{jobId=item.Id})'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        counter++;
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $(".table-striped").find("tr").each(function () {
            $("td").filter(function() {
                return $(this).text() === "Failed";
            }).parent().addClass("failed");
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to change the row color based upon td value if it is failed.
See actual output:
[image: Actual Output]

**Solved**

Comment: Your code seem to work fine: https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/ddxwYG?editors=1011 when hardcoding the result on the page. I wonder if it's some sort of async issue you are facing

Comment: Yes it is some async issue. Guys posted answers below that work on jsfiddle but not in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write any js code. You can directly add status class on `tr` tag

```
<tr class='@item.Status'>

.Failed {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not set the class directly in the razor code?

```
<tr class="@(item.Status == "Failed" ? "failed" : "")">
```

Comment: I would do it like this too, not sure why you would use js to do this

Comment: I am trying this.

Comment: That's pretty handy.

Comment: It is called a ternary operator. And they come in handy every now and then.

Comment: I know but I totally forgot about it :P

Answer (score 1):

add a class to your status column

```
<td class="status">@item.Status</td>
```

then in script :

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $(".table-striped").find("tr").each(function () {
           var status= $(this).find(".status").html();  
           if(status=="Failed")
             {
                    $(this).addClass("failed")
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

it will work. try it !